# Does JAXB offer a way to check if an object/xml is marshallable/unmarshallable?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have some code that marshals an object to an XML string to send it over JMS. However, before I actually call this code I would like to have an indication if the call would be succesful. Something like

```
JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class);
Marshaller m = ctx.createMarshaller();
if(m.canMarshal(o)) {
    return m.marshal(o);
} else {
    throw new MyJmsProtocolException("Could not marshal object of type " + o.getClass().getName());
}
```

Does this exist in JAXB (java 8)?

(Disclaimer: I checked the Marshaller object and googled and searched here, but the results seem loaded with validation checks, applying schema's etc.)

Comment: why not catch the exception during marshall and react to it?

Comment: This way I can skip the exception handling (cleaner in my opinion). It might also be faster (completely dependending on the implementation of course) if the object cannot be marshalled.

Comment: I doubt if there is any cleaner solution. Validation check can help, but it would be redundant say in case the object can be marshaled successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I use this

```
public Document JAXBObjectToDocument(Object JAXBObject) throws Exception {
    // si el objecto que recibimos en un objecto XMLRootElement, es decir el padre
    // de todo dios
    if (JAXBObject.getClass().isAnnotationPresent(XmlRootElement.class)) {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBObject.getClass());
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        DOMResult domResult = new DOMResult();
        marshaller.marshal(JAXBObject, domResult);

        return (Document) domResult.getNode();
    } else {
        throw new Exception("NO SE PUEDE CONVERTIR LA CLASE \"" + JAXBObject.getClass().getName()
                + "\" A UN \"org.w3c.dom.Document\"");
    }

}
```

I`m verify if the Object that I want to marshal is annotated with XMLRootElement